# Unable to upload files via form using Media Library on IPhone

Tags: php, html, iphone, file-upload

I have a simple form with input type="file".
It works well on all devices except IPhone.
At the same time, screenshots of the screen are attached to the form normally, but photos from the Media Library seem to be attached, even the thumbnail is displayed, but it says "0 photos", and nothing comes after submitting the form.

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="input-files" name="input-files[]" class="form-control form-control-sm" multiple="multiple">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" value="Добавить">
    </form>
```

P.S. I Tried to remove multiple - the problem was not solved.